# JS Function is executing twice. 2 Records are generated from postinstallment function

Tags: javascript, json

below script is posting the data in database twice. There are 2 tables. Installments table is fine. only single entries but contract table is posting 2 records.

```
function fillInsBreakup() {
        var brkuptb = $("#tb1Installment");
        var customerName = $("#CustomerName").val();
        var NoofInslmnts = $("#NoOfInstallment").val();
        var insStartDate = $("#InstallmentStartDate").val();
        //console.log(insStartDate); //yyyy-mm-dd passed to above variable
        var insFreq = $("#InstallmentFreq").val();
        var signAmt = parseFloat($("#ContractSigningAmount").val());
        var dowPmt = parseFloat($("#DownPaymentAmount").val());
        var paidamt = signAmt + dowPmt;
        //        console.log(paidamt);
        var remamt = parseFloat($("#ContractAmount").val()) - parseFloat(paidamt);
        //      console.log (remamt);
        var insAmt = remamt / NoofInslmnts;
        var Unit = $("#Unit").val();`enter code here`

        //var insstartdate = $("#DownPaymentDate").val();
        var dt = new Date(insStartDate);
        for (var i = 1; i <= NoofInslmnts; i++) {

            // var cDate = Date(insstartdate);

            var brkup =
                "<tr class='brkup-row'><td>" +
                "I" + customerName.slice(0, 3) + Unit + i
                + "</td><td>" +
                customerName
                + "</td><td>" +
                Unit
                + "</td><td>" +
                i
                + "</td><td>Installment"

                + "</td><td>" +
                parseFloat(insAmt).toFixed(2)
                + "</td><td>" +
                dt.toISOString().split('T')[0]
                + "</td></tr>";

            dt.setMonth(dt.getMonth() + parseInt(insFreq));

            brkuptb.append(brkup);




        }


    }
```

This is the function which is executing 2 times
function postInstallment() {

```
        var ListOfInstallment = new Array();
        var NewContract = {}



        NewContract.ContractID = $("#ContractID").val();
        NewContract.CustomerName = $("#CustomerName").val();
        NewContract.PropertyName = $("#PropertyName").val();
        NewContract.Unit = $("#Unit").val();
        NewContract.ContractStartDate = $("#ContractStartDate").val();
        NewContract.ContractAmount = $("#ContractAmount").val();
        NewContract.ContractsignDate = $("#ContractsignDate").val();
        NewContract.ContractSigningAmount = $("#ContractSigningAmount").val();
        NewContract.DownPaymentDate = $("#DownPaymentDate").val();
        NewContract.DownPaymentAmount = $("#DownPaymentAmount").val();
        NewContract.InstallmentFreq = $("#InstallmentFreq").val();
        NewContract.NoOfInstallment = $("#NoOfInstallment").val();
        NewContract.InstallmentStartDate = $("#InstallmentStartDate").val();


        $('.brkup-row').each(function (index, tr) {
            var Installments = {};
            var InsNo = index;

            Installments.ContractID = $("#ContractID").val();
            Installments.InstNO = $(this).find("td:eq(3)").text();
            Installments.InstallmentType = $(this).find("td:eq(4)").text();
            Installments.InstallmentAmt = $(this).find("td:eq(5)").text();
            Installments.InstallmentDate = $(this).find("td:eq(6)").text();

            //Installments.InsNO =$(this).find("td:eq(3)").text()
            ListOfInstallment.push(Installments);
            console.log(Installments);



        });
        console.log(ListOfInstallment);
        NewContract.ListOfInstallment = ListOfInstallment;

        //alert(NewContract);
        //alert(ListOfInstallment.val());
        //alert(Installments.val());


        $.ajax({

            async: true,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            contentType: 'application/json, charset=utf - 8',
            data: JSON.stringify(NewContract),
            url: '/Contract/Create',
            success: function (data) {


            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Problem with saving data")
            }

        });



    }
```

using .done to post but also same result
var dfd = $.Deferred();
dfd
.done([fillInsBreakup, postInstallment]);

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#calcinst").click(function () {
            fillresAmt();
            filldownpayment();
            fillInsBreakup();

        });
        
        $("#save").click(function () {
          
            dfd.resolve();

            
     
        });
    });
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack-Overflow! We're glad to have you! I've noticed that your title is not in the form of a question. In order for other coders to best assist you we ask that you follow the guidelines here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: can you create a working fiddle reproducing your error.